# [C#][Steamkit2] Sending a Lobby Chat Message

Tags: c#, byte, message

I've been trying to use Steamkit2 to send a message to a CSGO Lobby.
I have used the Hook and the Analyzer to get from steam what function is called when you send a message.

So first I connected to my csgo lobby!

```
var JoinLobby = new ClientMsgProtobuf<CMsgClientMMSJoinLobby>(EMsg.ClientMMSJoinLobby);
JoinLobby.ProtoHeader.routing_appid = 730;
JoinLobby.Body.app_id = 730;
JoinLobby.Body.persona_name = "DEIN-NAME-HIER";
JoinLobby.Body.steam_id_lobby = (ulong)109775243834561419; // Lobby link 109775243834561419/76561198312797851
Console.WriteLine(JoinLobby.Body.steam_id_lobby);
Client.Send(JoinLobby);
```

now that I have gotten a "OK" response I want to send my message using this:

```
message CMsgClientMMSSendLobbyChatMsg {
  optional uint32 app_id = 1;
  optional fixed64 steam_id_lobby = 2;
  optional fixed64 steam_id_target = 3;
  optional bytes lobby_message = 4;
}
```

So I tried this:

```
var SendMessage = new ClientMsgProtobuf<CMsgClientMMSSendLobbyChatMsg>(EMsg.ClientMMSSendLobbyChatMsg);
SendMessage.Header.Proto.routing_appid = 730;
SendMessage.Body.app_id = 730;
SendMessage.Body.steam_id_lobby = 109775243834354861;
SendMessage.Body.steam_id_target = 109775243834354861;
//SendMessage.Body.lobby_message
```

But I dont know how I can write a text to "lobby_message" since its a byte.
Maybe you guys can help me :)

Comment: Can you help me here in commnents? When I send ClientMsgProtobuf<CMsgClientMMSJoinLobby> nothing happens. User is not joining lobby or anything. And how you're getting "OK" response?

Comment: P.S. You need to use Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Your message") to get byte[]

Comment: I think you are missing routing_appid = 730;
I dont know why, but it's needed.

Comment: No I'm not. I just copied your code to my app and still nothing. Do you have skype/discord? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Discord: Logxn#7243

Comment: Did this end up with a happy ending? I'd be very glad to see the final results of this.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string message to byte with below function

```
      static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            return bytes;
        }
```